# Is there a way to access specific attributes in a list of objects in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Alright, started learning python a while back, worked myself up to learning about OOP in general, then they tell me to write up a game of blackjack. Now, I made objects for every card, put all those objects in a list to simulate a deck. I'm having trouble to figure out how to cleanly return one specific attribute from every item in that list.

I originally just tried to print, but then I realised I thought the thing was smarter than it actually is, which was a problem. Python's a good language, and I'm sure the tools are there. I just don't know it yet

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self, face, suit, value):
        self.face = face
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value

ACES = Card("Ace","Spades",10)
TWOS = Card(2,"Spades",2)
THRS = Card(3,"Spades",3)
FOUS = Card(4,"Spades",4)
FIVS = Card(5,"Spades",5)
SIXS = Card(6,"Spades",6)
SEVS = Card(7,"Spades",7)
EIGS = Card(8,"Spades",8)
NINS = Card(9,"Spades",9)
TENS = Card(10,"Spades",10)
JACS = Card("Jack","Spades",10)
QUES = Card("King","Spades",10)
KINS = Card("Queen","Spades",10)

deck = [ACES,TWOS,THRS,FOUS,FIVS,SIXS,SEVS,EIGS,NINS,TENS,JACS,QUES,KINS]

print (deck.face)
```

In hindsight I should've realised the code would think I demanded an attribute from the list itself, not the items inside, but I'm stumped.

Comment: You will have to get a `Card` object by iteratign the list (`for card in deck:`) or by using an index (`card = deck[0]`), then you can access the attributes of it.

Answer (score 1):

> In hindsight I should've realised the code would think I demanded an attribute from the list itself, not the items inside

Actually, code doesn't "think", it is only executed. And the runtime doesn't "think" either, it just executes the code provided. But those minor conceptual nuances set aside, your diagnostic is right: `deck.face` looks up the attribute named "face" on the `deck` (list) object itself.

If your question is "how to print (or collect or do whatever with) the `face` attribute for each card in `deck`, the simple solution is to iterate on the list:

```
for card in deck:
    print(card.face)
```

or if you want to build a list of `face` values:

```
faces = [card.face for card in deck]
```

Now if it's an exercise in OO design, you may want to reconsider the use of a `list` to represent a "deck" object - a cards deck is actually not a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Since each element in deck list is Card Object, hence you need to iterate the list and get the face attribute as given below :

```
faceList = []
for obj in deck:
  faceList.append(obj.face)

print (faceList)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
deck = [ACES,TWOS,THRS,FOUS,FIVS,SIXS,SEVS,EIGS,NINS,TENS,JACS,QUES,KINS]

deck_faces = [card.face for card in deck]
print(deck_faces)
```

And this gives:

```
['Ace', 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'Jack', 'King', 'Queen']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a good solution would be using dictionaries, a dictionary allows you to keep even a string as a key for traversing a list, this is what you could do

```
cards_dict={"ACES": Card("Ace","Spades",10), "TWOS": Card(2,"Spades",2)}
```

and so on, you could then access the "ACES" card by directly querying it like this: `cards_dict["ACES"]`

or you could do this

```
cards_dict = {d.face: d for d in deck}
```

then you coudl directly query a card using the face name, as such: `cards_dict["Ace"]`

Comment: The way I set it up is that I use a random number to determine what card to pull from the list, a dict doesn't really allow that

Comment: Hi @Lurcolm, why don't you add that in the question? That could actually change some of the answers...

Comment: You could theoretically still work with dicts, list(dict.keys()) gives you all the keys in list form, you may then sample a random index number and index it via they keys list to get a random card

Comment: Or in that case just sample the keys list and then access the dict with that random key...

Answer (score 0):

just use a for loop for all of them

```
for card in deck:
    print(card.face)
```

or

```
deck[0].face
```

for specific item